Playwright - Get project name from env file
I want to keep project definitions in the playwright config file like:
projects: [
    {
      name: 'chrome',
      use: { browserName: 'chromium' },
    },
    {
      name: 'firefox',
      use: { browserName: 'firefox' },
    }
....
  ]

But instead of selecting the project from command line with

--project=chrome

I want to do that in my .env file.
Is it possible?
Tried overriding the process.env.project value but does not work.
I´m already reading values from .env file for other variables on my tests...

Yes it possible using the filter() method on projects array.
Here is a code example:
// playwright.config.ts

import { defineConfig, devices } from "@playwright/test";

require("dotenv").config();

const selectedProject = process.env.PROJECT || "all";

export default defineConfig({
  testDir: "./tests",

  use: { headless: false },

  projects: [
    {
      name: "chrome",
      use: { ...devices["Desktop Chrome"] },
    },
    {
      name: "firefox",
      use: { ...devices["Desktop Firefox"] },
    },
  ].filter(
    (project) => project.name === selectedProject || selectedProject === "all"
  ), // Optionally use "all" to run all projects,
});

Make sure to set the PROJECT env variable in your dotenv file,
with one of the defined project names, for example:
PROJECT = "firefox"

In this answer I've added the default option all in order to avoid the no tests found error in case of not setting the PROJECT env variable.
Please take a note though, you can remove the default option if you like, or even enhance this logic to be able to handle multi-project selection.

This is a nice trick showing the advantage of the executable pwt config! Thanks!

Yes! This is a game changer in configuring automation projects. Glad I could help.

This is just what I was looking for. I tried everything except a filter... Note: with TS it gives a warning for "No overload matches this call"... but it works. Quick fix: "//@ts-ignore" Lol... thanks a lot!

Interesting, I didn't got this warning... anyway, glad I could help!
